# Fill value on hidden django input field on ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model form and I'm manually entering the fields into my template.

Model form:

```
class ProductEntryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'image', 'product_name', 'price', 'options',
        ]
```

Manually rendering fields in Template:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <h2>New Product</h2>
   {% csrf_token %}

   {{ form.non_field_errors }}
   <p>
      <label for="">Image</label>
      {{ form.image.errors }}
      {{ form.image }}
   </p>
   <p>
       <label for="">Product name</label>
       {{ form.product_name.errors }}
       {{ form.product_name }}
   </p>
   <p>
       <label for="">Description</label>
       {{ form.description.errors }}
       {{ form.description }}
   </p>
   ...
```

The `options` field of the form is hidden in the template because the user doesn't fill this field directly. They fill it from a different input field.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
   <p style="display: none">
       {{ form.options }}
   </p>

   <input type="text" name="visible_option_input" :value="[[make_this_value_of_{{form.options}}_when_submitted]]">
   ...
</form>
```

I want the value of `"visible_option_input"` to be the value of `{{ form.options }}` when submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The way to do this is to render the django template form field explicitly (see this post on [simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html) for rendering django forms manually):

```
<p style="display: none">
   <input type="text"
      name="{{ form.options.name }}"
      id="{{ form.options.id_for_label }}"
      {% if form.options.value != None %}
         value="{{ form.options.value|stringformat:'s' }}"
      {% endif %}
      maxlength="{{ form.options.field.max_length }}"
      {% if form.options.field.required %}
         required
      {% endif %}>
</p>
```

I then used Vuejs to bind the value from the `visible_option_input` to the django field:
I replaced the django form value:

```
{% if form.options.value != None %}
   value="{{ form.options.value|stringformat:'s' }}"
{% endif %}
```

with:

`v-model="my_v-model_property"`

I used Vuejs but you can use plain js or any other tool you like.